# How do I prevent SoundEffect from playing before the page is fully loaded

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my windows phone 7 app I'm using the following code to navigate to a page

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Game.xaml, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
```

In the OnNavigatedTo event of Game.xaml.cs  I use the following code to play two wav files one after another.  In order for me to prevent both audio play at the same time,  I use while loop to wait until the first audio is finish before the second file is played.  I believe this is what causing the first audio to play before the game page is displayed.  Is there a better way of doing this?

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{            
    playAudio("intro.wav");
    while (MySoundEffect.State == SoundState.Playing)
    {
    }

    playAudio("firstQuestion.wav");

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);                 
}
```

The following is the code for playAudio.

```
 protected void playAudio(string fileName)
        {
            Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("audio/" + fileName);
            SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
            MySoundEffect = effect.CreateInstance();
            FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
            MySoundEffect.Play();
        }
```

MySoundEffect is a property of the Game class.

```
private SoundEffectInstance _MySoundEffect;

        public SoundEffectInstance MySoundEffect
        {
            get { return _MySoundEffect; }
            set { _MySoundEffect = value; }
        }
```

Whenever user click the button, the sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question in the title, you could try the same with the
   [`Loaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596558%28vs.95%29)
   event handler instead of the `OnNavigateTo`. This way, your audio files will start playing 
   only  after the page is loaded.